# How do I show Google Map on my android device?

Tags: android, android-studio

After running the app the screen is like this and it doesn't change over time.

[link of my android set while app is running][https://i.imgur.com/aEp6ZyG.png]

[This is the Link of the tutorial I followed from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fVhmtzwvfk&list=PLxefhmF0pcPlGUW8tyyOJ8-uF7Nk2VpSj&index=2&ab_channel=CodingCafe)

I did everything according to the tutorial but in my android device the map isn't showing .

Here is my MapsActivity.java code :

```
package com.example.findnearbyplaces;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Code of AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.findnearbyplaces">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FindNearbyPlaces">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code of activity_maps.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Seems like your code is perfectly fine and even working, But It's the speed of you internet which is not enough to fetch map

Comment: @UtaibaNaqshbandi I checked the speed while using normal apps . Speed is sufficient for browsing the web.

Comment: Have you tried it on Physical device?

Comment: @UtaibaNaqshbandi  Yes , I run the android project by connecting the android device with computer via usb.

Comment: Okay, Do one thing, extend your activity with `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` and then initialize your fragment as  `MyFragment myFragment;`

Answer (score 1):

**Try replacing your MainActivity with below code, and let me know the outcome.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
   
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

  

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(new LatLng(-34, 151))
          .title("Marker in Sydney")
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));



    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-34, 151), 10));
}
}
```

Comment: In case if the code above don't work, then try different location, as an example; instead of  `(-34, 151)` use `(37.4629101,-122.2449094)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the code below before 'getMapAsync(this)':

```
        mapFragment.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: I added the code line as per your reply but it still isn't working . Google map doesn't show.

Comment: Sorry, i missed one line. After that line i sent, add another one "mapFragment.onResume()")

Comment: Do I have to install something like "google play services" or any other module/program on my personal-computer to run google-map on android device through android-studio ?